# How to Add multi remote slave replicas to mysql db?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have one remote slave replica running , I want to add an additional one from a different remote server it also has the same db name as the first slave db, so obviously locally I'll rename it. I looked at the mysql documentation but couldn't figure out the sequence and required changes to the my.cnf file. so in sense the setup is:

```
Slave #1 Name:Foo IP: 100.100.100.001

Slave #2 Name:Foo (rename to Foo2) IP: 100.100.100.002
```

of course different dumps and log MASTER_LOG_FILE,MASTER_LOG_POS files for each your advise guys

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must use the replicate-rewrite-db Option in the [mysqld] section

like:

```
master_usa.replicate-rewrite-db=customer->customer_usa
master_emea.replicate-rewrite-db=customer->customer_emea
```

Here is the Doku : https://mariadb.com/blog/multisource-replication-how-resolve-schema-name-conflicts

Comment: I think i didn't understand  something or I'm missing information from my data supplier.
the sources have the same name/ db name,  they do have different IP.
in addition  do you need to separate:
slave-skip-errors 
per slave or is this a global param?

Comment: or i didnt understand. Do you want to replicate into the same schema on the slave ? You can only replicate from Server A Schema FOO to Server C Schema A_FOO and from Server B Schema FOO to Server C Schema B_FOO

Comment: yes you understood me correctly a schema for each master.
i have 2 different remote masters, the db name is FOO on both, I have a mysql dump from each master to add so Server A Schema FOO to Server C Schema A_FOO, Server B Schema FOO to Server C Schema B_FOO. So what I didn't understand is how to setup the source names (master_usa, master_emea) in the example command

Comment: Please take first a look in this doku: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/multi-source-replication/

 - the keyqord for google is "multi master replication" -- if there are more problems i can write you 3 configs

Comment: Hi I will require your assistance, I will need different connection names, these seem to be set on the master side correct?. I am btw on 5.6.28-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log, will this be an issue?

Comment: Yes this is correct. You can send me your my.cnf's to buffen@t-online.de  then i will change it and send it back and whenn everything works we only post the results

Comment: I did not get a reply from you, can this be done on mysql 5.6?

Comment: we can chat this evening if you want. the local time here is 11:30 and i am ca 19:00 at home